# embedded submanifold in euclidean space derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

Let $y$ be the coordinate function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider $\mathbb{S}^1$ as an embedded submanifold. If $p\in (1,0)$, how do I show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}|_p\in T_p\mathbb{S}^1$? It clearly is in $T_p\mathbb{R}^2$.

My attempt: Since $\mathbb{S}^1$ is defined by the smooth function $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$,

$T_p\mathbb{S}^1=Ker(F_{*,p})$ for all $p\in \mathbb{S}^1$.
Hence if $h\in C^{\infty}$, $F_{*,p}(\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}|_p)h=\frac{\partial{h\circ F}}{\partial{y}}|_p=0$

where the last equality holds because $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}}|_p=0$

Question 2: In Loring Tu's book, does the differentiable structure as constructed in Proposition 9.4, coincide with the differentiable structure as constructed in example 5.16 for the sphere?

Comment: That's not true. Draw a picture.

Comment: Could you look at page 217 in Loring Tu's book? it's literally the first line @Thorgott

Comment: You omitted the first part of that line, which is crucial.

Comment: Right, what about my argument now? @Thorgott (I added $p=(1,0)$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that argument works. Perhaps it wouldn't hurt to make the use of the chain rule explicit. Also note that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\Big\vert_p=0$ holds true precisely because $p=(1,0)$, this would fail at other points (convince yourself of this).

Alternatively, you don't need to be this abstract. Since we're working in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can identify all tangent spaces with subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big\vert_p$ is just the vector $(0,1)$ and, for all $p\in S^1$, the tangent space $T_pS^1$ is precisely the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ orthogonal to $p$. And, of course, $(1,0)$ is orthogonal to $(0,1)$ (this is what's illustrated in Fig. 19.1. in Tu's book).

Comment: Thanks! @Thorgott

Comment: another question @Thorgott. Related to the same problem. Does the differentiable structure as constructed in Proposition 9.4, coincide with the differentiable structure as constructed in example 5.16 for the sphere?If yes, whats the easiest way to see this? Ill add this question in my post above.

Comment: Yes. It suffices to check that the charts given in 5.16 are diffeomorphisms with respect to the smooth structure given in 9.4. But they are smooth since they're restrictions of smooth maps on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and their inverses are smooth, because they're smooth when considered as maps into $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: "are diffeomorphisms with respect to the smooth structure given in 9.4" Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm not sure which part of that you want elaboration on. Come to chat if you wanna discuss this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this is to actually produce a slice chart about $p=(1,0).$ Note that if $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ then $\partial f_x(1,0)=2\neq 0$ so if we set $\phi(x,y)=(f,y)$ then, we get a slice chart in a small neighborhood $p\in U\mathbb \subseteq R^2.$ That is, $(\phi|_{S^1},U\cap S^1)$ is a chart about $p$ in $S^1$. But $\phi|_{S^1}(f,y)=(0,y)\cong y$ and so $T_pS^1=\operatorname {span} \{\partial_y\}.$